# How do I bind some data from Angular without using np-repeat

Tags: angularjs

I am a day into learning Angular. I can retrieve data using $http.get but I would like to know how to bind data without using ng-repeat (because there will only be 1 item)

My code:

```
<html ng-app="league">
    <snip>
    <div ng-controller="LeagueController">
        <div ng-repeat="y in gamedata">
            <h2>Game Details</h2>
            <p>Game Date/Time: {{ y.GameDate + ' ' + y.GameTime }}</p>
            <p>Location: {{ y.GameLocation }}</p>
            <p>Opponents: {{ y.Opponents }}</p>
        </div>
    </div>
```

And I set gamedata like so

```
$http.get("getgamedetails.php?id=" + gameID + "").success(function(response)
{
    $scope.gamedata = response.gamedata;
});
```

I should add that $scope.gamedata is set after a click (ng-click) event, so if I use the current answer's solution the output is displayed (Game Date: ) without the data.

Comment: If only 1 item, why do you need ng-repeat then?

Comment: I am asking what is the correct way of doing it. What to use instead of ng-repeat

Comment: Use an expression such as: {{gamedata.GameDate}}

Comment: if its an array of data.. then you have to use ng-repeat

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you always have 1 element so don't return array from server, return object.
If you don't have an access to server code and you 100% know, that you have only one element in array so just get this element from array and bind:

```
$scope.gamedata = response.gamedata[0];
```

And your html bind will be without foreach binding:

```
<html ng-app="league">
    <snip>
    <div ng-controller="LeagueController">
        <div>
            <h2>Game Details</h2>
            <p>Game Date/Time: {{ gamedata.GameDate + ' ' + gamedata.GameTime }}</p>
            <p>Location: {{ gamedata.GameLocation }}</p>
            <p>Opponents: {{ gamedata.Opponents }}</p>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: But then before $scope.gamedata is set the HTML is rendered without the gamedata.GameDate, etc

Comment: Just add ng-if="gameData" on container where this model bind

Comment: and this block will be render after model will get value

Comment: Thanks, you are a superstar

Answer (score 0):

You don't need ng-repeat to bind data, in fact two-way binding is built right into Angular without doing much work.

In your case you should have something along this lines (not the [ng-show](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngShow) directive, this allows you to hide the gamedata when it hasn't loaded):

```
<html ng-app="league">
<snip>
<div ng-controller="LeagueController" ng-show="gamedata !== null">
    <h2>Game Details</h2>
    <p>Game Date/Time: {{ gamedata.GameDate }} {{ gamedata.GameTime }}</p>
    <p>Location: {{ gamedata.GameLocation }}</p>
    <p>Opponents: {{ gamedata.Opponents }}</p>
</div>
```

Controller:

```
// Initialize the gamedata as null or some empty value.
$scope.gamedata = null;

$http.get("getgamedetails.php?id=" + gameID + "").success(function(response)
{
     // Assuming the server response is an array
     $scope.gamedata = response.gamedata[0];
});
```

*Alternatively*, you can use the [ngBind](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngBind) directive.

```
<html ng-app="league">
<snip>
<div ng-controller="LeagueController">
    <h2>Game Details</h2>
    <p>Game Date/Time: <span ng-bind="gamedata.GameDate"></span> <span ng-bind="gamedata.GameTime"></span></p>
    <p>Location: <span ng-bind="gamedata.GameLocation"></span></p>
    <p>Opponents: <span ng-bind="gamedata.Opponents"></span></p>
</div>
```

Comment: Okay but $scope.gamedata is set in response to user clicking on a game, so until that happens this shows Game Date/Time: blank , Location: blank, etc. Do you know what I mean?

Comment: I have added an extra "ng-show" in the HTML so the information is only shown when gamedata has loaded (not null).